# Assistance with awk/bash to plot memory difference

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file which consists of the following information in repeating blocks.

**First iteration**

```
xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB   <<<<<<<<<< START TIME
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB   <<<<<<<<<< END TIME
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:41:08.084 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2550   sysdb_svr_local          7881443     7878256     -3187       87391
7582   mibd_interface           8670334     8484152     -186182     267657
```

**Second iteration**

```
xr_lab#show memory compare start
Thu Sep 19 14:43:07.946 WIB   <<<<<<<<<< START TIME
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_start.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare end
Thu Sep 19 14:45:27.916 WIB   <<<<<<<<<< END TIME
Successfully stored memory snapshot in /var/log/malloc_dump_memcmp_end.out
xr_lab#
xr_lab#
xr_lab#show memory compare report
Thu Sep 19 14:45:42.091 WIB

PID    NAME                     MEM BEFORE    MEM AFTER  DIFFERENCE MALLOCS-NEW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6777   ospf                     24294569    24283592    -10977      227389
7582   mibd_interface           8369050     8514825     145775      126259
```

I would like to capture the {start time, mem_before} in one column, and {end time, mem_after} in another column for mibd_interface.

**Initial attempt:**

```
awk '/show memory compare start/{
             getline; start=$0;
  }
     /show memory compare end/{
             getline; end=$0;
  }

     /mibd_interface/ {for(i=3; i<5; i++){print start,$i,end,$i}}' file.txt
```

**Output**

```
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB 8670334
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB 8670334
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB 8484152
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB 8484152
```

**Desired output**

```
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB 8670334
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB 8484152
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I achieve the desired output above?
2. How can I format the date into dd-mm hh:mm:ss format? Eventually I would like to feed the data into gnuplot to plot the desired output above, with time on x-axis and memory on y-axis.

Reference question:
[Assistance with awk/bash to capture memory difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200564/assistance-with-awk-bash-to-capture-memory-difference/58200799?noredirect=1#comment102783547_58200799)

Thanks.

Comment: change `print start,end,$i` -> `print start,$i; print end,$i` ? `dd-mm hh:mm:ss` awk has that [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function, but it needs _exactly_ `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]` format, which in your case `Sep` is hard to do. So first extract the dates with number with ex. `,` as a separator using awk, and then for each line feed the date to GNU `date` and convert it to timestamp in the format you want. If you want performance in converting date to your format, there is [strptime from dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/)

Comment: @user, could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're working too hard at the print stage.  Isn't this all you want?

```
/mibd_interface/ {
    print start, $3, "\n" end, $4
}
```

Modified in that way, I get:

```
$ ./report.awk data
Thu Sep 19 14:38:06.400 WIB 8670334 
Thu Sep 19 14:40:56.123 WIB 8484152
```

Note that because the newline string isn't followed by a comma, it's concatenated to `end`, which is what you want, else a space is introduced as a field separator at the start of the 2nd line.

You could also use two `print` statements, of course.